# How to verify a shopify webhook request in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, shopify

Can someone explain how do I compute a HMAC

===============

## To verify that the request came from Shopify, compute the HMAC digest according to the following algorithm and compare it to the value in the X-Shopify-Hmac-SHA256 header. If they match, you can be sure that the Webhook was sent from Shopify and the data has not been compromised.

## Each Webhook request includes a X-Shopify-Hmac-SHA256 header which is generated using the app's shared secret, along with the data sent in the request.

I have the secret key... how can I combine the secret key + the data in the request to generate a HMAC

Comment: Also, make sure you have the correct secret key; there are two. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44763029/1455074

Comment: Have you been able to find the right "secret key" ? I can't find the shared secret key in the partner dashboard.

Comment: @tschwab , what you have mentioned in the linked question, if the app is a public app, how will I get the "---MY_REAL_SHARED_SECRET---" from each of the store where my shop is installed? I sounds like a no brainer to me. What you said works for webhooks created manually by the store admin but not something created by public apps using API. Any light on this?

Comment: @HymnZ, I am not sure, I only messed around with Shopify's API for a few weeks. I am pretty sure what I was doing was just for the webhooks, like you said. I don't know about public apps. However, there is a lot of information on API credentials here: https://help.shopify.com/api/getting-started/api-credentials

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to use the [ShopifySharp Library](https://github.com/nozzlegear/ShopifySharp). You can use the Nuget package and install it in your project.

This is an example taken from the ShopifySharp website for validating webhooks:

```
NameValueCollection requestHeaders = Request.Headers;
Stream inputStream = Request.InputStream;

if(AuthorizationService.IsAuthenticWebhook(requestHeaders, inputStream, shopifySecretKey))
{
    //Webhook is authentic.
}
else
{
    //Webhook is not authentic and should not be acted on.
}
```

If you don't want to use ShopifySharp, you can see how they implemented it in the [source code](https://github.com/nozzlegear/ShopifySharp/blob/master/ShopifySharp/Services/Authorization/AuthorizationService.cs).

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

string shopifySecretKey = "c016fb163da3a6fa9ecf7db9f25b1e7c25ef2a7ccdb13df380e8f09324cf0124";
    using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    requestBody = readStream.ReadToEnd();
}

bool OK = IsAuthenticWebhook(Request.Headers, requestBody, shopifySecretKey);
    
bool IsAuthenticWebhook(NameValueCollection requestHeaders, string requestBody, string shopifySecretKey)
            {
                var hmacHeaderValue = requestHeaders["X-Shopify-Hmac-SHA256"].ToString();
    
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hmacHeaderValue))
                {
                    return false;
                }
    
                //Compute a hash from the apiKey and the request body
                string hmacHeader = hmacHeaderValue;
                HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(shopifySecretKey));
                string hash = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody)));
    
                //Webhook is valid if computed hash matches the header hash
                return hash == hmacHeader;
            }
}
```

Comment: Based on the code in ShopifySharp